# SEMC HSUSB Driver - Windows 7. How do I get to install this thing?

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers

I'm trying to connect my Android phone to my PC.
I know, I know. That's not an SU question, but hear me out.

The whole problem seems to be one single .inf / driver file which I just cannot manage to install.
See title.

I've been reading and reading through forums but I couldn't find a solution.
It's a driver for USB devices but.... I have no idea what it is.

More information:
[image]

Comment: Actually, questions regarding hooking up a phone to a PC _IS_ a valid SU question, especially since your problem seems to exist on the PC's end. :).  It's just kind of a weak "question" as-is.  Here's a couple questions for you though:  What exact phone make and model is in question?  Where from did you get the drivers you are attempting to use?  Are they the latest versions available from the manufacturer?  What have you tried already (aside from reading forums) to rectify the problem?

Comment: Maybe you can identify the device using [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-find-unknown-device-drivers-by-their-vendor-device-id/).

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/all-downloads/

Select your phone and download the driver.

Now go to `Device Manager`. Right click on the `SEMC HSUSB Device` and select `Properties`.

Now select the path where you downloaded the driver.